# glBitmap: bitmap size issue

Tags: opengl, bitmap, byte, raster, opengl-compat

I have a doubt trying to understand and use glBitmap function.
I started from [this example](https://www.opengl.org.ru/docs/pg/0801.html) and trying to draw a 40x40 "bitmap" and avoiding a [situation like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921254/scale-glbitmap-drawing) I tried this:

> 40 x 40 is 1600 bits -> so I need 200 bytes of info (1600/8)

```
GLubyte rasters[ 200 ] =
{
    0xff, 0xff, //.. and so on 200 times
};


 // main code calling the function below

void display(x, y)
{
    float size = 40.0;
    glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glRasterPos2i(x, y );
    glBitmap(size, size, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, rasters );
}
```

I was expected to draw a fully green square 40 x 40 pixel. Turns out that I met the [unwanted situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921254/scale-glbitmap-drawing) instead with the dirty upper part of the square. It seems that `raster[200]` is enough to draw only a 32 x 32 bitmap. So what I would like to ask:

1. what's wrong in my math (or in understading the example)?
2. what I need to have in my raster to draw a 40x40 (and why, next step I will need to draw something playing with the bits, so how to now were pixel (x,y) is located)
3. final goal is drawing something starting from a GLubyte array, is there a way to do the same with glTexImage2D? (I tried to followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339877/glbitmap-questions) but I failed)

Comment: Sorry that I am not answering your question, but I suggest you not to try understanding this API as it is deprecated many years ago. Try to use modern OpenGL.

Comment: @MichaelIV can you point me in the right direction telling me an equivalent "modern" OpenGL function?

Comment: You don't have such a function in the modern API because it doesn't work in immediate mode. You have to create textures, shader programs, some geometry (quad in your case) and render. Yes it comes with more manual setup than the old one, but it also provides you with more power and flexibility to render stuff. You can begin here http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/

Comment: https://learnopengl.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to set the alignment. By default OpenGL assumes that the start of each row of the raster is aligned to 4 bytes. This is because the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter by default is 4. Each row in the raster has 5 bytes (40 / 8 = 5). Therefore you need to change the alignment to 1:

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glBitmap(size, size, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, rasters);
```

Comment: Very clear answer, now I understand. Thank you @Rabbid76.